# Почему не отображаются слайды Swiper?

Tags: javascript, slider, слайдер, swiper

Есть слайдер, зацикленный. Но что через свайп, что через навигацию - когда доходит до последнего слайда, то вот такая картина

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

стоит еще раз свайпнуть или нажать Next, то все ок
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и так по кругу. Хотя если начать свайпать/навигировать в обратном направлении, то такого эффекта нет.

```
 const authorsSlider = document.querySelector('[data-popular-authors-slider]');

  if (authorsSlider) {
    sliderBreakpoints(
      '[data-popular-authors-slider-pagination-mobile]',
      '[data-popular-authors-slider-pagination]',
      1024
    );

    const authorsSwiper = new Swiper(authorsSlider, {
      slidesPerView: 1,
      slidesOffsetBefore: 10,
      watchSlidesVisibility: true,
      watchSlidesProgress: true,
      pagination: breakpointsPagination,
      loop: true,
      spaceBetween: 10,
      slidesOffsetAfter: 0,
      navigation: {
        nextEl: '[data-popular-authors-slider-right]',
        prevEl: '[data-popular-authors-slider-left]'
      },
      breakpoints: {
        768: {
          slidesPerView: 3,
          slidesOffsetBefore: -70,
        },
        1024: {
          slidesPerView: 4,
          slidesOffsetBefore: 0,
        }
      }
    });

    authorsSwiper.update();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

slidesPerView: 6 от 1024 - решило вопрос